# Core 2.1 HttpRequest.Body is empty when trying to read it

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, httpwebrequest, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I am trying to read stream data from HttpRequest.Body but I am getting empty string. 
The request is send here from .net project

```
        HttpWebRequest request = null;
        Uri uri = new Uri(**Endpoint**);
        UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(message);
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        using (Stream writeStream = request.GetRequestStream()) {
            writeStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        try {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch {
            lock (endpointLock) {
                _pushHttpEndpoint = null;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

The request is send here.This is .net core 2.1 application. I am trying to read the data in request body but that is returning empty

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post()
    {
        var bodyStr = "";
        var req = HttpContext.Request;           
        req.EnableRewind();            
        using (StreamReader reader
                  = new StreamReader(req.Body, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true))
        {
            bodyStr = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }    

        req.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        //do other stuff
        return bodyStr;
     }
```

Can someone please help me with this.
We are in position where we cannot change the .net solution code. Any changes should be done in .net core solution side. We are trying to fit the new api in place of existing Endpoint. :(

Comment: Check my answer.  I just did this very same thing in .Net Core 2.2.  It might work for you.

Answer (score 4):

First I know the question is asking about ASP.NET Core 2.1 but I had the same problem on 2.2.

This is how I solved it:

The way to enable this in ASP.NET Core 2.2 is the following:

First enable Buffering at the request pipeline level.  This is done in the Startup.cs class.

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
  {

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
      //enable buffering of the request

      context.Request.EnableBuffering();

      await next();

    });
  }
```

Second inside your action:

```
  Request.EnableRewind();
  Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

  using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.ASCII))
  {
    var requestBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
    // Reset the stream just in case it is needed further down the execution pipeline       
    Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
  }
```

Comment: Didn't help either

Comment: @Naruto how did it not help? I have this code in production.... So how did it not work for you?

Comment: tried many things, but this one helped me. :-) Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I just tested this in .NET Core 3.1. Works as advertised.

Answer (score 1):

Your type is "type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded" , so use [FromForm] attribute . Code below is for your reference :

.Net project :

```
        HttpWebRequest request = null;
        Uri uri = new Uri("https://localhost:44365/Home/Post");
        UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        var postData = "thing1=hello";
        postData += "&thing2=world";
        byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        using (Stream writeStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            writeStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                //return true;
            }
            else
            {
               // return false;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
```

On your .net Core Project :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post([FromForm]AcceptValue acceptValue)
    {

        //do other stuff
        return "";
    }

    public class AcceptValue {
        public string thing1 { get; set; }

        public string thing2 { get; set; }
    }
```

[image: Result :]

Comment: Actually we are trying to hack our code. The problem is that the data cannot be sent in this way. 
var postData = "thing1=hello";
postData += "&thing2=world";
.Net code is the old one and we are in situation not to change that. Data that is sent can be any format and we need that in .net core solution. Any changes should be done in .net core solution side. We are in tricky position. :(

Comment: Please check my answer.  I just did this in ASP.NET Core 2.2.  I am not sure if it will work for ASP.NET Core 2.1.  But I know it works for 2.2

Answer (score -3):

You should use the [FromBody] attribute.

It will be this:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Post([FromBody] object body) {
// do stuff here
}
```

Comment: This doesnt help. [FromBody] for "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" request gives  415 unsupported media type error in .net core.

Comment: @Amrutha , FromBody is used for json type , you should use FromForm if the type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded .See my reply